# MsDeploy parameters.xml: howto refer a parameter?

Tags: parameters, package, msdeploy, webdeploy

Currently I'm trying to create a Web Deploy Package. So I've added a parameters.xml to the root of my project and specified some custom parameters.
I found that a lot of my parameters were partially the same. So I want to do some sort of a parameter referencing. Looking for this, I came accros [Reference for the Web Application Package](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/windows-web-application-gallery/reference-for-the-web-application-package). There it says the following:

> Hidden - A Hidden parameter is not shown to the user as part of the installation UI. A Hidden parameter must have a defaultValue set. These parameters are used either to set a hard-coded default value or to set a computed default value. Hard-coded defaults are sometimes used when establishing a parameter for future use. Computed values are used to construct a parameter’s value from other parameters. When constructing computed values, you can refer to other parameters by putting the other parameter name surrounded by {}s in the place you want the value. Please refer to the "Connection String" parameter in the example for a common usage of this tag.

So, according to the documentation a parameter "vdeHostName" can be referenced from "vdeDashboardAddress", by setting the attribute defaultValue="https://{vdeHostname}/" and tags="Hidden" on "vdeDashboardAddress".

This led me to the following code for the parameters.xml:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="vdeHostname" description="Please provide the hostname" defaultValue="www.test.com">
    <description culture="en">The hostname of the website.</description>
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile"
                    scope="obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp\\Configuration\\hosts\.config$"
                    match="/hostConfigurationSection/hostConfigurations/add[@name='Default']/@host" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="vdeDashboardAddress" defaultValue="https://{vdeHostname}/" tags="Hidden">
    <description culture="en">The https address of the Dashboard.</description>
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile"
                    scope="obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp\\Configuration\\identity\.config$"
                    match="/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration[@name='Default']/audienceUris/add/@value" />
  </parameter>
<parameters>
```

However, this seems not to be the case. It does not reference/replace the parts of the attribute in the defaultValue.
This is currently being outputted:

```
<audienceUris>
  <add value="https://{vdeHostname}/" />
</audienceUris>
```

The only thread I found here mentioning anything about my problem is at [How to get Deploy.cmd to fill in replacement fields from Parameters.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137773/how-to-get-deploy-cmd-to-fill-in-replacement-fields-from-parameters-xml)

1. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?
2. Is the specification incorrect? Then, how does one do partial replaces in the parameters.xml?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards, rdvanbuuren

Comment: I've the same problem. Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: No, I've not come across any solution yet. The only solution I've come up with is just write it completely, instead of using replaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the `scope` attribute looks suspicious to me. All the scope elements in the (working) parameter file I've got in front of me are of the form `scope="\\Path\\To\\File\.extension$"` where the path specified is assumed to start at the root folder where the application is deployed. (E.g. the most common is `scope="\\Web\.config$"`.) None of the scope attributes in my working file include the Package\PackageTmp part of the path, even though that path is present in the zip file that WebDeploy consumes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is not possible to accomplish that sort if substitution via a parameters.xml file. In my case, I had to do so with a [publish profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (or .wpp.targets file).

This method excludes the parameter you are trying to sub into from being included in the setparameters.xml file, which seems to be the key to getting the substitution working when you use the .Deploy.cmd to import.

So, you should be able to follow the above link's instructions to create a targets file. Then, you are going to want something like the following in the file (based on your original example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" BeforeTargets="Package">
        <ItemGroup>

            <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="vdeHostname">
                <Kind>XmlFile</Kind>
                <Scope>Web.config</Scope>
                <Match>/hostConfigurationSection/hostConfigurations/add[@name='Default']/@host</Match>
                <Description>The hostname of the website.</Description>
                <Value>www.test.com</Value>
                <DefaultValue>www.test.com</DefaultValue>
            </MsDeployDeclareParameters>

            <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="vdeDashboardAddress">
                <Kind>XmlFile</Kind>
                <Scope>Web.config</Scope>
                <Match>/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration[@name='Default']/audienceUris/add/@value</Match>
                <Description>The https address of the Dashboard.</Description>
                <DefaultValue>https://{vdeHostname}/</DefaultValue>
                <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
                <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
            </MsDeployDeclareParameters>

        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

The magic here is made possible by the ExcludeFromSetParameters element, it keeps vdeDashboardAddress out of the .SetParameters.xml file thus allowing the substitution to work. Obviously, you would want to remove the corresponding stuff from your parameters.xml

One caveat though: verify the scope is correct (per the other answer). This example I provided assumes this stuff lives in web.config

Answer (score 0):

I see one possible problem in the parameters.xml: your xml root `<parameters>` tag is not closed. So I would suggest to replace the last line with `</parameters>` and try again